# What is the type of an intersection type according to the Java Language Specification?

Tags: java, jls

During my question I refer to the Java Language Specification in the third edition. According to the specification of the intersection type (§ 4.9) the intersection type `int[]` (or `int[] & int[]`) would have the same members as a class type with an empty body and the direct superclass `int[]`. But the way I understand the specification, a class type may not have an array type as an super type, because §8 tells:

> Each class except Object is an extension of (that is, a subclass of) a single existing class (§8.1.4) and may implement interfaces (§8.1.5).

Do I understand something wrongly or is it an inconsistency in the specification?

Comment: both `int[]` and `long[]` are objects, so their intersection is also an object. Also, a class with an empty body is just this class: `public class Empty {}` which still implicitly extends Object.

Comment: §4.9 tells that for all types of the intersection type `int[] & long[]`:

Comment: "Then the intersection type has the same members as a class type (§8) with an empty body" What makes you think that this class type with an empty body, doesn't extend another class?

Comment: §4.9 tells that for all types Ti of the intersection type `int[] & long[]` the most specific class or array type Ci is determined, which is a supertype of Ti. Thereafter, the most specific Ci (Ck) is determined. The Ck is then the supertype of the class with the empty body. In the given example this Ck is `int[]`, isn't it? Can then a class type exist which extends an array type?

Comment: `long[]` does not extend `int[]`, so no.

Comment: `(Object)new long[1] instanceof int[]` is false

Comment: I just recognized that according to §4.10.3 `int[]` and `long[]` do not stand in the subtype relation. Thus I choose a better example: I use the intersection type consisting of the single type `int[]`.